# How to make mahout interact with hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout

I am using HDP mahout version 0.8. I have set `MAHOUT_LOCAL=""`. When I run mahout, I see the message `HADOOP LOCAL NOT SET RUNNING ON HADOOP` but my program is not writing output to HDFS directory.

Can anyone tell me how to make my mahout program take input from HDFS and write output to HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the `$MAHOUT_HOME/bin` and `$HADOOP_HOME/bin` on the PATH ?

For example on Linux: 

`export PATH=$PATH:$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/ 
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/conf/`

Then, almost all the Mahout's commands use the options -i (input) and -o (output).

For example:

`mahout seqdirectory -i <input_path> -o <output_path> -chunk 64`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your mahout jar build which takes input  and write to hdfs. Do the following:

From hadoop bin directory:

```
./hadoop jar /home/kuntal/Kuntal/BIG_DATA/mahout-recommender.jar mia.recommender.RecommenderIntro  --tempDir /home/kuntal/Kuntal/BIG_DATA --recommenderClassName org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericItemBasedRecommender

#Input Output Args specify if required
-Dmapred.input.dir=./ratingsLess.txt -Dmapred.output.dir=/input/output
```

Please check this:
http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/playing-with-the-mahout-recommendation-engine-on-a-hadoop-cluster/